# Swift Playgrounds crashing when running at different speeds

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift-playground

I have this code in viewDidAppear

```html
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) { 
        BGAmbient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: arView.center.x*2, height: arView.center.y*2)
        BGAmbient.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: BGred, green: BGgreen, blue: BGblue, alpha: BGalpha)
        arView.addSubview(BGAmbient)
     
        let imageName = "Title.png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        var locX: CGFloat = 0
        var locY: CGFloat = 0
        var x: CGFloat = 0.7
        var y:CGFloat = 0.4
        x = arView.center.x - arView.center.x * x
        y = arView.center.y - arView.center.y * y
        var w = arView.center.x * CGFloat(2) * 0.7
        var h = arView.center.y * CGFloat(2) * 0.4
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: x,
                                 y: y,
                                 width: w, height: h)

  }
```

I'm running it on an iPad in swift playgrounds right now. However, it always crashes either on `arView.addSubView(BGAmbient)` or let imageView = `UIImageView(image: image!)`.

But, it doesn't crash when running on Xcode or in step-by-step mode on the iPad.
What is the issue?

Comment: If it's crashing here ` let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!).` There is possibility that image you are trying to create in first line is not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine if I put code in Sources folder. Seems like it's a Swift Playgrounds bug.